# Ruby on Rails 4 bootstrap datetimepicker setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a newby struggling to get bootstrap datetimepicker to work. Could somebody help me out with setup ?

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require nested_form_fields
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/core
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.et.js
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

trainings.coffee

```
$('#training_start_time').datetimepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm' });
```

view

```
= form_for @training do |f|
...
    = f.text_field :start_time, :data => { :provide => 'datetimepicker', date_format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm' }, :value => f.object.start_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: As a matyter of fact js console shows errors Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your javascript codes to coffee script style.

```
$('#training_start_time').datetimepicker format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm'
```